# AppCenter - Prevent packages from updating

Tags: release-loki, updates, appcenter

I need a couple of older libraries to make a program work. I can hold the packages with the following commands:

```
apt-mark hold package
echo package hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

That way when I try to upgrade the system through `apt full-upgrade` the system holds the packages correctly.

However, if I try to upgrade through the AppCenter, the packages are upgraded despite of the previous orders to `apt` and `dpkg`.

How can I prevent AppCenter from upgrading certain packages?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this one? I guess perhaps CLI upgrade is the only way for you unless anyone else has wisdom to share.

Comment: Have you tried using Synaptic for this? I don't recall the steps but I know you can lock specific versions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried blacklisting some specific versions of the packages? I guess this should help for at least a while!

```
Package: compiz-plugins-main
Pin: version 1:0.9.7.0~bzr19-0ubuntu10.1
Pin-Priority: -1
```

This goes into the `/etc/apt/preferences file`.

[As mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/a/322945/64901)

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work yet: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/544

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past. I run Unifi Controller on this desktop and I didn't want the system to update the version I was running due to some issues that I wanted to see get worked out first.  "sudo apt-mark hold unifi" did exactly that and I updated everything else for a few weeks like normal until I was ready to update unifi. "sudo apt-mark unhold unifi" released the hold.
"sudo apt-mark showhold" to check it.